# Не переведено сообщение об изменении

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, правки

Не переведено сообщение, всплывающее, когда текст был отредактирован во время просмотра:

[image: An edit has been made to this post]

Answer (score 4):

Перевод был добавлен:

> Это сообщение было отредактировано

Изменения вскоре отобразятся на сайте. Спасибо за помощь!